# How to write a batch file to copy directories recursively and then create a short cuts for them in the source folder.

Tags: batch-file, dos

I need to create a batch file which can perform following actions.

1. Copied directories and sub directories from source folder older than 10 days to destination folders.
2. Delete copied directories from source folder and create short cuts for that in source folder.

I have written the following batch file. But I am not getting proper result which I want.

---

```
@echo off
@echo copying file to Archive folder
xcopy c:\tempMovetoUDrive U:\Archive /e/d:03/20/2012
pause

@echo creating a shortcut for copied files
set SHORTCUT_NAME=Shortcut to copied files
set SHORTCUT_PATH=C:\tempMovetoUDrive
set PROGRAM=U:\Archive
set WORK_DIRECTORY=C:\tempMovetoUDrive
set ICON_FILE=%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\SHELL32.dll
set ICON=4
set WINDOW_STYLE=1

echo SET oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > tempshortcut.vbs
echo sLinkFile = "%SHORTCUT_PATH%\%SHORTCUT_NAME%.lnk" >> tempshortcut.vbs
echo SET oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> tempshortcut.vbs
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%PROGRAM%" >> tempshortcut.vbs
echo oLink.IconLocation = "%ICON_FILE%, %ICON%" >> tempshortcut.vbs
echo oLink.WindowStyle = "%WINDOW_STYLE%" >> tempshortcut.vbs
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%WORK_DIRECTORY%" >> tempshortcut.vbs
echo oLink.Save >> tempshortcut.vbs

WScript.exe tempshortcut.vbs
rem del tempshortcut.vbs
```

---

Appreciate your time and help with this.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry i couldn't provide a comment , hence writing it in answer. The script above does work for me, you said its not proper, so what exactly is the issue are you facing.